# Cuda profiler shows strange gaps?

Tags: optimization, cuda, profiling, nvvp

I am trying to figure out what a profile result means, before I start to optimize. I am very new with CUDA and profiling in general and I am confused by the result.

Specifically, I want to know what is happening during seemingly unoccupied chunks of computation. When I look from top to bottom at the CPU and GPU there appears to be nothing happening during large portions of the code. These look like columns with nothing in `Thread1` and nothing in `GeForce`. Is this normal? Whats happening  here?

The run was done a multicore machine under no load with nvprof. The GPU code was compiled with `-arch=sm_20 -m32 -g -G` for CUDA 5.

[image]
[Larger Image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/screenshot121212055101.png/)

Comment: Is this windows or linux?  If windows, is the GPU in question also hosting the display?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Linux, I don't believe there is a physical display on this machine although vnc is turned on.

Comment: I guess X is enabled since you mention vnc.  If so, is the GPU in question called out with a relevant Display section in the xorg.conf file?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Is this really an explanation for this effect? It would seem that the CUDA portion occupies significantly less than half the GPU. I could see this being the case for a machine that is under OpenGL load, but not my machine.

Comment: It could be that those gaps are caused by the profiler, as it is collecting the metrics and saving them to disk.

Comment: @Mikhail The Thread and GeForce row are parent rows and never contain content. The Thread row is a parent row for Runtime API, Driver API, and NVTX rows. The GeForce row is a parent row for your CUDA Device. The sub rows show multiple views of memory copies and kernel launches. If you look at only the Runtime API, Profiling Overhead, and Stream 2 row you can get a good idea of your execution. At ~400µs/pixel there is insufficient detail. The GPU work is close the to CPU work which leads me to believe the CPU thread is busy doing non-CUDA work. Can you post the code or an API trace?

Comment: @Roger Dahl, The Visual Profiler shows when it is adding overhead in the Profiling Overhead row so I don't think that is the cause. Its definitely a good point to consider as tools overhead can impact the performance of a CPU or disk bound application.

Comment: Did you test this in release? (without those debug flags)

Comment: @BenC Should I? Does the profiler work without `-G`? There are a few things on my plate and I expect to get back to this question in a few days.

Comment: @Mikhail: yes it does (at least with CUDA 5.0).

Comment: @BenC Your suggestion worked, can you post a formal answer to this question?

Comment: @Mikhail: absolutely, thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error here was to profile the code in debug mode (`-G` compiler flag: "Generate debug information for device code"). The behavior of the program is deeply changed, and this should not be used to profile and optimize one's code.

One other thing: a thorough documentation of **nvcc**'s debug mode is hard to find. **nvcc** probably dumps the registers/shared memory in global memory for easier host access and debugging, which may in turn hide problems such as race conditions in shared memory (cf. discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10726970/1043187). Thus, programs such as `cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck` should be used in release mode too.